# Google chrome is not showing arrow sign

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have added left/right arrow sign for a slider using jquery. It's showing perfectly in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but google chrome is showing a box instead of arrow sign([www.unitechbd.com](http://www.unitechbd.com)). How can I solve it?

Jquery code  -

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                        $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
                          animtype      : 'fade',

                          showcontrols : true, // show next and prev controls
                          centercontrols : true, // center controls verically
                          nexttext : '&#10095;', // Text for 'next' button (can use HTML)
                          prevtext : '&#10094;', // Text for 'previous' button (can use HTML)
                          showmarkers : false, // Show individual slide markers
                          centermarkers : true, // Center markers horizontally

                          animduration : 1000, // how fast the animation are
                          animspeed : 5000, // the delay between each slide

                          width         : 922,
                          height        : 500,            
                          usecaptions : false,
                          responsive    : true,
                          randomstart   : true
                        });

                      });
```

Comment: It looks fine on my browser. Chrome Version 38.0.2125.122

Comment: I have checked it using Version 39.0.2171.71, but same result, showing a box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes seems Chrome has problems with [❮ & #10094;](http://unicode-table.com/de/276E/).

You could use [fontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/angle-left/) or the like to get that.